# Can't figure out Bus Error:10 when reading file

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list, bus-error

I am making a program that reads a text file and puts it into a linked list before carrying on with the other functions. The program also involves a thread function that operates every 5 seconds but the crash is happening at startup. Here is my code for the functions causing problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//Strucutres
#define NODE struct node
struct node {
    int number;
    char name[20];
    NODE *next;
};

#define LIST struct list
struct list {
    NODE *head;
    NODE *tail;
};

#define PARAM struct param
struct param {
    char filename[20];
    LIST *listpar;

};

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

//Declare functions
void read_file(LIST **, char *in);
LIST * add(LIST **list, char *fake, int fakenumber);
void show(LIST **list);
void delete(LIST **list);
void dispbin(char *input, LIST **list);
void *autosaver(void *arg);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    LIST *list;
    FILE *in;
    PARAM *newP;
    printf("%s",argv[1]);
    printf("%s",argv[2]);

    pthread_t thr;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    if ((list=(LIST *)malloc(sizeof(LIST)))==NULL) {
        printf("No memory available");
        return 2;
    }
    list->head=NULL;
    list->tail=NULL;
    if (argc==1) {
        printf("No files entered");
        return 1;
    } else if (argc==2) {
        printf("Text file entered but no binary file entered");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("Reading file");
        read_file(&list, argv[1]);

    }
    strcpy(newP->filename,argv[2]);
    newP->listpar=list;

    printf("About to create");
    pthread_create(&thr, NULL, autosaver,(void *)newP);
    int whileLoop=0;
    int tempnumber;
    char tempName[20];
    while (whileLoop==0) {
        newP->listpar=list;
        int selection;
        printf("\nPick an option:1)Add New Party 2)Enter Open Table Size 3)Show Text List 4)Show Binary Autosave 5)Quit: ");
        scanf("%d",&selection);
        NODE *new=list->head;
        switch(selection) {
            case 1:
                printf("\nWhat is the name of the party? ");
                scanf("%s",tempName);
                printf("\nWhat is the size of the party? ");
                scanf("%d",&tempnumber);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                add(&list,tempName,tempnumber);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                break;
            case 2:
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                delete(&list);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                break;
            case 3:
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                show(&list);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                break;
            case 4:
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                dispbin(argv[argc-1],&list);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                break;
            case 5:
                pthread_cancel(thr);

                if ((in=fopen(argv[argc-2],"w"))==NULL) {
                    printf("File not found");
                    return 3;

                }
                fprintf(in, "Name Group Size\n-------------\n");
                while (new!=NULL) {
                    //printf("Hi2");
                    fprintf(in,"%s %d\n",new->name,new->number);
                    new=new->next;
                }
                fclose(in);
                whileLoop=1;
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nWhat is the name of the party? ");
                scanf("%s",tempName);
                printf("\nWhat is the size of the party? ");
                scanf("%d",&tempnumber);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                add(&list,tempName,tempnumber);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                break;




        }
    }


}

void read_file(LIST **list, char *in) {
    printf("%s",in);
    printf("Start of read function");
    printf("\n");
    int seats;
    char name[20];
    FILE *infp;
    if ((infp=fopen(in,"r"))==NULL) {
        printf("File not found\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("Opened");
    fseek(infp, sizeof(char)*strlen("Name Group Size\n-------------"),SEEK_SET);
    printf("Seeked");
    while (fscanf(infp,"%s %d",name,&seats)!=EOF) {
        add(list, name,seats);
    }
    fclose(infp);
    printf("End of read function");
    return;
}
LIST * add(LIST **list, char *fake, int fakenumber) {
    printf("\n");
    NODE *new;
    NODE *temp;
    if ((new=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE)))==NULL) {
        printf("No memory!");
        return *list;

    }
    if ((*list)->head==NULL) {
        strcpy(new->name,fake);
        new->number=fakenumber;
        (*list)->head=new;
        (*list)->tail=new;
        new->next=NULL;
        return *list;
    }
    temp=(*list)->head;
    while (temp!=NULL) {
        if (strcmp(fake,temp->name)==0) {
            printf("Name already taken");
            return *list;

        }
        temp=temp->next;

    }
    if ((new=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE)))==NULL) {
        printf("No memory");
        return *list;
    }
    strcpy(new->name,fake);
    new->number=fakenumber;
    (*list)->tail->next=new;
    (*list)->tail=new;
    new->next=NULL;

    return *list;

}
```

Comment: how did you run your binary? `printf("%s",argv[1]);` and `printf("%s",argv[2]);` are provided without `NULL` check...

Comment: Fyi: `strcpy(newP->filename,argv[2]); ` and `newP->listpar=list;` The pointer `newP` is uninitialized going in to both of those. Eg. you're invoking undefined behavior as your program is ill-formeed.

Comment: ...and, can you please use a debugger like `gdb` to pull out little more info , please?

Comment: @WhozCraig ..also `strcpy(newP->filename,argv[2]);`

Comment: the return statements, after a failure of malloc() are not good enough because they will return to the statement after the call to the function.  What should be done is call exit(somepositivenumber);

Comment: the code should check the returned values from the fseek() and fscanf() functions to assure successful operation and act accordingly when the function returned value indicates a failure (usually call perror() then call exit(somepositivenumber)

Comment: this line: NODE *new; in the add() function should not use the name 'new' as that is a keyword of the C++ language (and your probably using a C++ compiler to compile this C program.  With all warnings enabled, a warning/error message will be raised over using a keyword name for a variable name.

Comment: this second call to malloc() in the function add() overlays the pointer in the variable 'new', resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: in the call to read_file() there is no need to take the address of list, as the address value is not being changed, only a couple of fields and list is already a pointer to a allocation in memory

Comment: for a number of reasons, casting the returned pointer from malloc() is undesirable

Comment: the code is printing the strings at argv[1] and argv[2] before checking that the arguments were actually supplied

Comment: fscanf(), in read_file() does not null terminate input conversions using %s, so passing the read in parameter to add() where add uses a string function on that parameter, will result in undefined behavior and probably a seg fault event.